Magento New Order Email Payment Method Address Alignment
M2 sales related  transactional emails Magento use variable {{var payment_html|raw}} to add information and this information is added using HTML tag <dl><dt><dd></dd></dt></dl> and <dd> tag has default style margin-inline-start: 40px how to remove this style and also from where I can override this  {{var payment_html|raw}}  template.
I have already overridden vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml to app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Payment/templates/info/default.phtml and changed and applied CSS but it is not working.

you can find the payment_html content or data in vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php
payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order)

so override this and make the html change you want.
Or try to override order_new.html to a custom module or theme and adjust payment_html  with your custom payment variable.
